# How to to animate circular progress bar with spring animation in Android Kotlin, not the normal animation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-progressbar, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android

I have a circular progress bar(fitness tracker) I want to animate the "**progress**" with spring animation using damping and stiffness.
Not the normal animation.

Answer (score 4):

You can use jetpack compose using a [**`CircularProgressIndicator`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#CircularProgressIndicator(kotlin.Float,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp)) and applying a [`ProgressIndicatorDefaults.ProgressAnimationSpec`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/ProgressIndicatorDefaults#ProgressAnimationSpec()) animation.

```
    var progress by remember { mutableStateOf(0.0f) }
    val animatedProgress by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = progress,
        animationSpec = ProgressIndicatorDefaults.ProgressAnimationSpec
    )

   CircularProgressIndicator(progress = animatedProgress)
```

Finally assign the `progress` value.

Otherwise you can use a custom `animationSpec` like:

```
val customProgressAnimationSpec = SpringSpec(
    dampingRatio = 1f,
    stiffness = 50f,
    visibilityThreshold = 1 / 1000f
)
```

[image]

Comment: Currently we are not using jetpack in our project
Can I achieve this without jetpack?  At final position of progress it should show spring behaviour.